# Seeking is not smooth

Tags: directshow, seekbar, directshow.net, seek

**Situation**: I've created a seek bar for my video.

**Issue**: Seeking is not as smooth as I would like.

I've implemented seeking using IMediaPosition instead of IMediaSeek.

```
public virtual double Position
{
    get
    {
        if (mediaPosition != null)
        {
            double xPosition;
            mediaPosition.get_CurrentPosition(out xPosition);
            return xPosition;
        }
        return 0d;
    }
    set
    {
        if (mediaPosition != null)
        {
            int hr = mediaPosition.put_CurrentPosition(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The values I am setting as I MouseDown and MouseMove (continuous seek)

```
0.0570514459889382
0.0570514459889382
0.0760685918978415
0.0950857460689731
0.114102891977876
0.133120046149008
0.152137183795683
0.171154337966815
0.190171492137946
0.209188646309078
0.228205783955753
0.247222938126884
0.266240092298016
0.285257229944691
0.304274367591366
0.323291538286954
0.342308675933629
0.361325846629217
0.380342984275892
0.399360121922567
0.399360121922567
0.418377292618155
0.437394430264831
0.456411567911506
0.475428738607094
0.494445876253769
0.513463013900444
0.532480184596032
0.551497322242707
0.570514459889382
0.589531597536057
0.608548735182732
0.627565938927233
0.627565938927233
0.646583076573908
0.665600214220583
0.684617351867258
0.703634489513934
0.722651693258434
0.74166883090511
0.760685968551785
0.77970310619846
0.798720243845135
0.81773738149181
0.836754585236311
0.855771722882986
0.874788860529661
0.893805998176336
0.931840273469686
0.969874614860862
0.988891752507537
1.02692602780089
1.06496036919206
1.06496036919206
1.08397750683874
1.10299464448541
1.14102891977876
```

They seem accurate enough to provide a smooth seeking however it's not smooth at all. It's rough and jaggedy, seems to skip frames.

Comment: As far as I've seen, seeking behavior depends highly on your filter graph and especially the capabilities (and configuration) of your encoder/decoder and container filters.

Comment: Thanks @MikeDinescu